# Batch - Why archive is not being renamed?

Tags: batch-file

So, as we all know, when we use batch file to move archive to folder, where another archive with the same name exists, batch script will just replace old Archive.

Since I am making Archivating system, this is really bad, because important data may be lost in a proccess of archiving, hence, I made ticket in SO, to get information on how to fix this issue. Here is my test code:

```
set year=%DATE:~6,4%

if not exist "V:\01_%YEAR%" mkdir "V:\01_%YEAR%"  - Creates folder 01_2016
for /d %%X in (01_%YEAR%) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\" - Archivates folder
MOVE "V:\01_%YEAR%.7z" "Z:\"  - moves Archive.
```

User named [elzooilogico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6404553/elzooilogico), suggested, instead of Move command, to use this:

```
set "last=0"
set "filename=Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z"

if exist "Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z" (
    for /R %%i in ("Z:\01_%YEAR%(*).7z") do (
       for /F "tokens=2 delims=(^)" %%a in ("%%i") do set "last=%%a"
    )
    set/a last+=1
    set "filename=Z:\01_%YEAR%(%last%).7z"    
)    

MOVE "V:\01_%YEAR%.7z" "%filename%"
```

Unfortunetely I still did not understand, why did code not work, so I remade it a bit, and here is what I came up with.

```
set YEAR=%DATE:~6,4%
set filename=C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\01_%YEAR%.7z

cd /d C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder
if not exist "C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\01_%YEAR%" mkdir "C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\01_%YEAR%"
for /d %%X in (01_%YEAR%) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"
    if exist "C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\vairis\01_%YEAR%.7z" (
       for /R %%i in ("C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\01_%YEAR%(*).7z") do (
          for /F "tokens=2 delims=(^)" %%a in ("%%i") do set "last=%%a"
    )
    set/a last+=1
    set "C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\01_%YEAR%(%last%).7z"    
)    
MOVE "%filename%" "C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\vairis"
```

Could someone please explain to me, why is Archive name not being renamed after script checks, if Archive already exists?

Regards, Vairis

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: Could you please "show", how to debug only rename part of code?  I don't understand debugging process, from link that you gave me.

Comment: As that link suggests look at the values of the variables you are working with. Hint #1: `filename` is not defined. Hint #2: `set "C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\01_%YEAR%(%last%).7z"` doesn't do what you want it to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OK, new approach

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set/a last=1
set "YEAR=%DATE:~6,4%"
set "myFolder=C:\Users\PP_lemev\Desktop\New folder\vairis"
set "filename=%myFolder%\01_%YEAR%.7z"

if exist "%myFolder%\01_%YEAR%.7z" (
  for /R %%i in ("%myFolder%\01_%YEAR%(*).7z") do set/a last+=1
  set "last=000!last!"
  set "filename=%myFolder%\01_%YEAR%(!last:~-4!).7z"    
)    

for /d %%X in (01_%YEAR%) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%filename%" "%%X\"

endlocal
```